# Python while loop + check if integer or not, then saving to a file

Tags: python, input, while-loop, integer

I've been stuck on this for some time now. I'm making a quiz app, and I need to save the users score. The app will ask the users to enter a number from 1 to 3 so that they can save their score into a file, that will either save it in file 1, 2 or 3 (for 3 different classes).

If the user enters a letter then they will be asked to enter a number, and if the number isn't between 1 and 3 then it will ask them again until there's input is valid. Then it will save their score into the file.

```
classname = int(input("\nEnter [1] for class 1 \nEnter [2] for class 2 \nEnter  [3] for class 3"))
invalid = True

while invalid = True:
    classname = int(raw_input("Please enter a number in the range 1 to 3: "))
    if int(classname) >= 1 and int(classname) <= 3:
        invalid = False:

    while invalid = False:
        if int(classname) == 1:
            score = str(score)
            f = open("class 1.txt", "a")
            f.write(str(name+': '))
            f.write(str(score))
            f.write('\n')
            f.close()

       elif int(classname) == 2:
           score = str(score)
           f = open("class 2.txt", "a")
           f.write(str(name+': '))
           f.write(str(score))
           f.write('\n')
           f.close()

       elif int(classname) == 3:
           score = str(score)
           f = open("class 3.txt", "a")
           f.write(str(name+': '))
           f.write(str(score))
           f.write('\n')
           f.close()
       else: #not sure what to put here
```

I didn't know what to put for else. I am new to Python and I really need help with this as I just want to complete it. If someone could fix my code that would be greatly appreciated.

I think I need to use `type(classname)` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `else` statement.

Since you are taking the `classname` as an integer, you can catch the all errors with try-except. So basically you will check the input is an integer or not.

```
try:
    classname = int(input("\nEnter [1] for class 1 \nEnter [2] for class 2 \nEnter  [3] for class 3"))
except:
    print ("It's not a number, please try again.")
    continue
if 3 < classname or classname < 1:
    print ("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.")
    continue
```

The `continue` statement will pass all over the things until the user enter a number, then it will check is the number between 1 and 3. If it's not between 1 and 3, then it will pass all over the things until user enter an acceptable number.

Comment: it says 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: You have to put it into while loop.

Answer (score 0):

you should learn about regular expressions and the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
only_numbers=re.compile("^[0-9]+$")
good_one=re.compile("^[1-3]$")

usr_input=str(raw_input("Please enter a number in the range 1 to 3: ")
while True:
  while not only_numbers.match(usr_input):
    usr_input=str(raw_input("a NUMBER in the range 1 to 3: ")
  if good_one.match(usr_input):
    break
  else:
    usr_input=str(raw_input("in the RANGE 1 to 3: ")

outint=int(usr_input)
```

Comment: It says 'while True:' is an invalid syntax

Comment: Just tested the code, works for me as is, on python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you don't even need to check if it is a letter. I am assuming that if the answer given is anything but a 1, 2, or 3, you will reject it. So, all you need is an `else` statement, and just put the code that you want to do if they enter an invalid response.

If you really want to check the type of the answer, you can either check if the input is a letter:

```
if isalpha(classname):
    //Do stuff here
```

Or check if it is not an integer in general:

```
if type(classname) != int:
    //Do stuff here
```

However, if the user enters a letter, your program will not even get to this conditional to check it, because you immediately attempt to convert the input to an integer at the top. If the input is a letter, this will immediately throw an error. Therefore, GLHF's answer above would be an ideal solution to fix your code.